# Setting a dropdown value according to the current user

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set the dropdown option to the current user

I am already retrieving the current user name through the currUserName variable

I have tried this

```
$("#approversSelectBox option[value='" + currUserName +"']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the value of jquery dropdown  as follow:

```
$("#approversSelectBox ").val(currUserName);
```

refer [Live example](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-set-a-dropdown-box-value-in-jquery/)

Comment: :`currUserName` is actually a variable

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is set the select's value

`$('#approversSelectBox').val(currUserName);`

Assuming that your select has an option element with value exactly as that of `currUserName`